# Do we need to provision twice the number of rWCUs as needed for total application writes for DynamoDB Global tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

As per best practices mentioned in - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_reqs_bestpractices.html#globaltables_reqs_bestpractices.tables, it is recommended that we provision 2x the total number of application writes (rWCU) for each replica table.

> The provisioned replicated write capacity units (rWCUs) on every replica table should be set to the total number of rWCUs needed for application writes across all Regions multiplied by two. This accommodates application writes that occur in the local Region and replicated application writes coming from other Regions. For example, suppose that you expect 5 writes per second to your replica table in Ohio and 5 writes per second to your replica table in N. Virginia. In this case, you should provision 20 WCUs to each replica table (5 + 5 = 10; 10 x 2 = 20).

Shouldn't 10 WCUs in each region be enough? (5 for local writes (N.Virgina) and 5 coming from the replicated region (Ohio) ?)

What am I missing here?

If there were three regions us-east-1, us-west-2 and eu-west-1, each needing 5, 10 and 15 writes respectively in their local regions, then I'd expect each table to be provisioned at 5+10+15 = 30rWCU for each table and pay only for a total of 90rWCUs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mistake to me, AFAIK the provisioned amount of rWCU should be the WCU per second, in this example 5 * number_of _replicas^2 => 5*2^2 =20 rWCU **TOTAL**. As described on the DynamoDB Global tables price samples.

[AWS Global Tables Pricing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3oB8.png)

If you have the same global table in 3 regions the total would be (WCU*R^2) 5*3^2=45 rWCU Total.

My problem with this model is that we are already paying for the WCU on the original table, why do we have to pay for rWCU on the same table? We should pay only (WCU*2R) => 5*2*3 = 30rWCU. But what can we do... (MongoDB Atlas?)

Comment: Just simulated these scenarios on AWS Calculator, and it seems the math is WCU * 2R. The descriptions should be more clear.  Anybody that has already used the service??

Answer (score -2):

I hate designing on AWS for this reason.  It takes us so much "thinking" to understand things for ourselves (the sole reason being the weird and creative terminology of AWS). Now, Imagine explaining your recommendation/decision for "rWCU" to the rest of the IT team - with clear budget implications!

Here's the explanation:-

- 5 WCU in Ohio
- So, 5 WCU extra to replicate into N.Virginia
- 5 **DIFFERENT** WCU originating in N.Virginia
- Another 5 WCU needed now for replicating (bullet #3) **into** Ohio

Clearly, a Global-table is meant to have users hitting EVERY region that it is in.

For every second.

As per the quoted AWS documentation, it is *trying* to say that you have 5 WCU happening in Ohio, while **SIMULTANEOUSLY** in N. Virginia you have another group of users causing another 5 (diffferent) WCU happening.

Still not getting the math!?  Welcome to distributed computing.

P.S: Software Complexity is just getting geometrically worse by the decade.